# Attaching Click event to Bootstrap Toggle Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-2.0

I have a boostrap toggle with the code below. It is visually working right

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="showBuildQuantity" autocomplete="off" checked>Build Quantity
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="showNumberOfScreens" autocomplete="off" onclick="showBuildQuantity()">Number of Screens
        </label>
    </div>
```

Below it I have some code to handle click events:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showBuildQuantity').on('click', function () {
        <code here>
    });

    $('#showNumberOfScreens').on('click', function () {
        <code here>
    });
});
```

The issue I am having is that the click event's are never run when I click the toggle buttons.

I have other buttons on the same page using the same kind of jQuery click event and they do not have an issue.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @Rayon Thanks! I added it, the issue is that the .on events never fire and the functions are never called.

Comment: What is the output of console? Are there any errors? Normally your code seems to work as shown in this codePen so try to add more info http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/oLrvxq

Comment: @Kamil Zajac, yes, I have jQuery 2.2.4 and the latest version of bootstrap.  It might be an issue caused by the 2 interacting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I found I need to use change instead of click.  So the code should look like this:

```
$('#showBuildQuantity').on('change', function () {
    if (myChart != null) {
        myChart.destroy();
    }
    setChart(getBuildQuantityData);
});

$('#showNumberOfScreens').on('change', function () {
    if (myChart != null) {
        myChart.destroy();
    }
    setChart(getNumScreensData);
});
```